# Display data from dropdown in another div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a dropdown with a list of values that are pulled from a MySQL database. Each of these values has other corresponding attributes in the database. This is the structure of that table:

id | name | password

The dropdown values are basically just all of the values in the "name" column.

What I'd like to do is display the id/name/password for a selected dropdown value in a separate div. That is, if I select "MIT" from the dropdown, I'd like the div to show me the id and the password associated with MIT. If I select "Harvard", I'd like the div to show the id and password associate with Harvard.

**I am just looking for high-level suggestions on how I should approach a setup like this.**

I was thinking of using AJAX and passing the selected value into a separate PHP file, which would then pull and display the associated ID and password. The div would then contain code to make a call to that PHP file and display the values on that page.

I think it'd work in theory, but it seems a bit cumbersome...any ideas for simplifying the process?

Comment: I like your idea, the only alternative i can see is to populated the web page with all the values (hidden) and chose what to display based on the selection - sounds dangerous when we are talking about 'passwords'

Comment: If there's no security requirement with the passwords this is probably easier to do with a big JSON structure. It sounds like you're going to absolutely require javascript anyway for the interface you're describing anyway. Is the user supposed to "submit" the school name ("MIT") before the id and password get shown?

Answer (score 0):

You could use data-attributes on your options. This would expose the passwords through the markup, but since they are accesible anyways through choosing the option in the dropdown, I guess this isn't an issue.

If you gave each option an attribute `data-password="thepassword"`, then you could `$("select").find(":selected").data("password")` to retrieve the password. Do the same with a `data-id` attribute, and you're golden.

Another solution would be to have a JSon structure with the option values as keys. Let's say `{"MIT":"1234","Harvard":"verysecret"}` and then use `$("select").change()` and `$(this).val()` to retrieve the corresponding passwords (and other data) from you JSon structure.